# $el.find(...).iCheck is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, icheck

I have use example on surveyJs for icheck, but why is error message appears as

> $el.find(...).iCheck is not a function

, I checked that JQuery and icheck library have been added into this project and page loaded before calling iCheck function.

http://surveyjs.org/examples/react/custom-widget-icheck/

```
import { iCheck } from 'icheck';
 var radioGroupWidget = {
 name: "icheck",
    isFit : function(question) { return question["renderAs"] === 'icheck'; },
    isDefaultRender: true,
    afterRender: function(question, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var select = function() {
          $el.find("input[value=" + question.value + "]").iCheck('check');
        }
        $el.find('input').iCheck({
          checkboxClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
          radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
        });
        $el.find('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
          question.value = event.target.value;
        });
        question.valueChangedCallback = select;
        select();
    },
    willUnmount: function(question, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        $el.find('input').iCheck('destroy');
    }
 }
CustomWidgetCollection.Instance.addCustomWidget(radioGroupWidget);
```

Comment: Do you use es modules or "es5 style" by adding scripts into html page?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use iCheck with SurveyJS out of the box using SurveyJS custom widgets.

```
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/surveyjs-widgets"></script>
...
```

Please check the [example](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=custom-widget-icheck&platform=jQuery&theme=default):

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your function inside 
 $(document).ready
In my case this code solved my error :

```
(function (window, document, $) {
            'use strict';
             var $html = $('html');
             $('input[name="myiCheck"]').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
             alert("You clicked " + this.value);
             });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```